# How do I solve this error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Consider this code:

```
Dim strUrl As String = "http://www.txtguru.in/imobile/api.php?username=username&password=password&source=senderid&dmobile=123456789012&message=message"
Dim request As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl)
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.EndGetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim s As Stream = DirectCast(response.GetResponseStream(), Stream)
Dim readStream As New StreamReader(s)
Dim dataString As String = readStream.ReadToEnd()
response.Close()
s.Close()
readStream.Close()
```

I get an error on `request.EndGetResponse()` and the error is:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'asyncResult' of 'Public Overridable Function EndGetResponse(asyncResult As System.IAsyncResult) As System.Net.WebResponse'.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing -

```
 Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.EndGetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

to

```
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to use the asynchronous version:

```
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.EndGetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Try using the synchronous one instead:

```
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```